# Spark dataframe adding new column issue - Structured streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I am using spark Structured streaming. I have a Dataframe and adding a new column  "current_ts".

```
inpuDF.withColumn("current_ts", lit(System.currentTimeMillis()))
```

This does not update every row with current epoch time. It updates the same epcoh time when the job was trigerred causing every row in DF to have the same values. This works well with normal spark jobs. Is this a issue with spark structured streaming ?

Comment: Hi @Nats, were you able to achieve this? I have similar requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Well spark records your transformations as lineage graph, and only executes the graph when some action is called. So it will call

```
System.currentTimeMillis()
```

when some action is triggered. What I didn't understand that what in it you find confusing or what are you trying to achieve. Thanks.

Comment: I am trying to add a new column with value of System.currentTimeMillis() for every record in the DF. But I end up with same value in the column even after couple of hours into running the structured streaming job.

Comment: Then you might want to add timestamp at the time of data insertion, and then use that data as DataFrame. Not using withColumn.

Answer (score 1):

Spark has a [function to create a column with current timestamp](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#current_timestamp--). Your code should look like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions

// ...

inpuDF.withColumn("current_ts", functions.current_timestamp())
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your method is that  use lit which is literal function or a constant.
Spark will treat that as constant which is passed from the driver.
So when you execute the job, the literal will be evaluated with the time you execute.
All records have the same timestamp.
You need to use function instead.
`current_timestamp()` should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`inpuDF.writeStream.partitionBy('current_ts')`

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it